# MS Word Metadata

Tags: microsoft-word, metadata, forensics

This semester my CS 1501 final was replaced with a take-home exam in the form of a word document to be edited and uploaded by the due date. Something went wrong on my end where the file did not upload, so I now have to prove I did not edit the file past the due-date or alter the local metadata. Unfortunately I have no online back-ups.

I truly have nothing to hide. I know there are computer forensics techniques for handling this but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: I don't think there is any way we can help you with this. Just come clean and explain things and if they don't take it, take your loss and ask for any way to get that grade and learn from the mistake and start making backups.

Comment: I agree with @LPChip and the comments you received earlier on StackOverflow. All I can suggest is that if you had *any form* of online backup at any point, you might have *a version* of your document that can be independently dated.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you don't back up your data, there's no way to prove the document's operating records.